# Wordpress Lightbox shows the first image only

Tags: wordpress, lightbox

I tried 3 different plugins for images Lightbox, but all of them (the first was Elementor's lightbox) are showing only the first image. I'm using Infinitifree hosting, so it can be the problem? I also unchecked the "lazy loading" for images.

Now I'm using SimpLy Gallery Block plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem might not be the hosting company but the plugin setting. Which theme are you using?

Comment: creativeily theme

Comment: Search for a plugin called 'Simple Lightbox' under plugins>Add New . Upon installation and activation you can easily specify the number of columns you need to have in your desired gallery page or page into which you want to insert the gallery. I usually go with three columns, anyway after that you can easily copy one of its shortcode on the right side and using the elementor page builder you're using or any builder, find the shortcode inserter by searching shortcode and paste the shortcode their.